What is the commutator of the lowering operator $J_-$ and the exponential of $J_z$, arranged so that the lowering operator is always to the right?
I'm trying to perform a computation closely related to the problem below. It's a tricky little problem which I imagine has been tackled in the literature before, but I've had no luck finding it. Figured I'd try my luck here.
The problem:
Take the usual angular momentum lie algebra written in terms of ladder operators, and in particular consider the commutation relation $[J_-, J_z]=J_-$.
Now, consider the following commutator  
$[J_-, exp(-ai J_z)]=\sum_n(-\frac{(ai)^n}{n!})[J_-, J_z^n]$.
Very generically, it can be written in the following form:
$[J_-, exp(-ai J_z)]=\sum_m c_m J_z^m J_-$.
Find the coefficients $c_m$.
One way to put the expression in this form is as follows:
It can be shown that $[J_-, J_z^n]= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}J_z^k J_- J_z^{n-k-1}$. One may then commute the $J_-$ in this result past the $J_z^{n-k-1}$, to produce another commutator with a lower power on the $J_z$, ie
$[J_-, J_z^n]= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}J_z^k J_- J_z^{n-k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}J_z^k ( J_z^{n-k-1}J_-+[J_-, J_z^{n-k-1}])$.
One can repeat this procedure on each new commutator until all terms have the $J_-$ on the right.
I have some idea how to go about the calculation from here but it becomes a bit of a mess, with sums over nested sums and rampant reindexing. I'm finding it rather technically difficult to extract a 'nice' expression at the end. Hoping there is a known result out there that I can compare to, or perhaps an easier path to the answer.

It is convenient to consider this problem in the basis of eigenvectors of the operator $J_z$. For any vector $|m\rangle$ such that
$$
J_z|m\rangle = m|m\rangle,
$$
the following equalities are true
$$
J_z J_-|m\rangle = (m-1)J_-|m\rangle
$$
and
$$
[J_-,\exp(-aiJ_z)]|m\rangle = J_-e^{-aim}|m\rangle - \exp(-aiJ_z)J_-|m\rangle = e^{-aim}J_-|m\rangle - e^{-ai(m-1)}J_-|m\rangle =
$$
$$
= (e^{-ai}-1)e^{-ai(m-1)}J_-|m\rangle = (e^{-ai}-1)\exp(-aiJ_z)J_-|m\rangle.
$$
Since the last equality is satisfied for any eigenvectors of the operator $J_z$, then
$$
[J_-,\exp(-aiJ_z)] = (e^{-ai}-1)\exp(-aiJ_z)J_-
$$
Now the expression on the right-hand side can be expanded into an infinite series, or one can try to find a polynomial expression in the case where the eigenvalue of the operator $J^2$ is fixed equal to $j(j+1)$.

The other answer is perfect, but a less direct simpler method is application of  Hadamard's lemma on the adjoint action, a trick you'll  may well be using once a month,
$$
e^{iaJ_z}J_- e^{-iaJ_z}= J_-+ ia[J_z,J_-] + \frac{(ia)^2}{2!}[J_z,[J_z,J_-]]+ ...\\
= J_-( 1-ia +\frac{(ia)^2}{2!}+...)= J_-e^{-ia}.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $e^{-iaJ_z}$ nets you
$$ [J_-, e^{-iaJ_z}]=(e^{-ia}-1)e^{-iaJ_z}J_- ~~.$$
